# How to Handle images with file system mern

Tags: mongodb, react-native, amazon-s3, multer, mern

Now i upload photos with mongodb and multer and save them in static folder.

```
`Uploads/`
```

I dont understand where its actually saved if i deploy my app.
I need to upload all photos to external filesystem?
I heard a lot about s3 but its dont free ,there is another that made this job? . And also i dont understand how can i connect my mongodb collections with the images from other filesystem.. and i dont find a beginner tutorial for this. Please help  for understand it.

Answer (score 0):

This way is a little bit confused because you have to save somewhere else your photo, heroku cannot save photos. A good way is cloudinary and then take the url from mongo.